# redirect stderr of ldconfig from make to log file

Tags: redirection, stderr

A recent bzr branch broke my system and I'm having to boot into recovery mode to look at the source.  In the recovery mode command line you cannot scroll.  So I'm trying to recompile from source and am getting errors from ldconfig when running make.  I can't actually see where the error is originating from because I can't scroll.

When I do the regular make > log 2>&1 all I get in the log file is make's stderr and not ldconfig's.  Is there a way to redirect ALL stderr to a file from any subsequent commands that are called from the one command line entry?
Thanks

Comment: Your command should do just that.

Comment: Are you still seeing ldconfig output on the tty, or did it just disappear? Either way would be unexpected but knowing which one would help. Also, does the make print the ldconfig command line? And can you replicate it by running ldconfig alone from the prompt?

Comment: One more thing: can't scroll? What kind of console is that? Shift+PgUp has worked in the primitive text console ever since I started using Linux 18 years ago. Of course it doesn't go back for thousands of lines... also use ScrollLock or Ctrl+S to pause (Ctrl+Q to unpause) if your reflexes are fast enough. Or run `script` to save the output of an interactive session as a `typescript`.

Comment: Right, ldconfig output still appears on the tty while make outputs to the logfile, but running ldconfig from the prompt doesn't fail because the libraries aren't installed.
I was unaware of the Shift+PgUp hotkey but there wasn't enough history to go all the way back to the error. I'll try to pause it but would still be interested as to how to get this to work.
Sorry for the late response, I didn't get an email notification.